# How do I set a constexpr variable to an ordinary variable?

Tags: c++11, multidimensional-array, constexpr

I'm making a two dimensional array, a dynamic array containing several static arrays (of shorts):

```
constexpr unsigned char constColumnMax = columnMax; //wrong
using column = std::array<short, constColumnMax>;
column * row = new column[rowMax];
row[0][0] = 10;
```

Where `columnMax` is an unsigned char that has a value set by a previous function, the column definition makes up the static arrays, & the row array is a dynamic array of columns.

The problem with this is that my code to set the constexpr, `constColumnMax` equal to `columnMax` is wrong. However, the variable that I put into `std::array<>` has to be the constexpr type.

I'm at a dead end here. The only thing I can think of is using a loop to increment `constColumnMax` which won't work for obvious reasons. Any help you guys can give would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You, sir, are out of luck. The value of a `constexpr` must be known at compile-time; as with the size of `std::array`. See http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constexpr

Comment: So I have no choice but to use a vector?

Comment: @Larrimus Pretty much. Functions can also be `constexpr` so if somehow you can make all the data in the function be known at compile time then you can use `std::array`. But I'm guessing that's not possible in your case.

Comment: Umm... I tried creating a vector of arrays with: `std::vector<std::array<short, columnMax>>` & I receive the same error saying that the expression `columnMax` must have a constant value.

Comment: @Larrimus You can't use std::array at all and use `columnMax`. No matter its location (i.e., inside a vector) the size has to be known at compile time.

Answer (score 1):

The promise of constexpr is that it can be evaluated at compile time.
The implementation of array is close to an implementation like `type name[size]` where size has to be a constant expression.

[Here](http://www.stroustrup.com/C++11FAQ.html#constexpr) is the general Idea behind constexpr explained.
[Here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B14#Relaxed_constexpr_restrictions) are some notes of the changes from C++11 to C++14.

Here are two alternatives:

- Use a vectors so you can grow the array naturally
- Move the responsibility up the hierarchy with templates

Here are some snippets to flesh out the idea a bit more:

```
#include <array>
#include <vector>

template<typename T, size_t R, size_t C>
using Array2D = std::array<std::array<T, R>, C>;

template<typename T, size_t R, size_t C>
void templatedFunction()
{
    Array2D<short, R, C> arr;
    arr[0][0] = 0;
}

template<typename T>
using Dynamic2D = std::vector<std::vector<T, std::allocator<T>>, std::allocator<T>>;

template<typename T>
void dynamicFunction(size_t R, size_t C)
{
    Dynamic2D<T> arr;
    arr.reserve(R);
    for (size_t n = 0; n < R; ++n)
    {
        arr.emplace_back(C);
        arr[n].emplace_back(0);
    }
}

int main()
{
    templatedFunction<short, 4, 5>();
    dynamicFunction<short>(4, 5);
}
```